# In Chrome Bootstrap keeps changing vertical gap between images in a grid

Tags: css, image, layout, grid, positioning

I have a grid of images for a gallery and it looks good in some cases where the browser is a certain width, but when you shrink the size of the browser in Chrome it changes the vertical gap between items. In Microsoft Edge, it works as expected (not tried Firefox). I need to keep the vertical gap consistent and only roughly 10px in height.

Here is the difference between browsers:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sLrb.jpg

To try this out for yourself, use Chrome and check out the results from the link below and resize the preview window to trigger the breakpoints.

https://www.codeply.com/go/DUmlhXetYE

If you cannot repeat the problem then maybe it's a browser update issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove `display: flex;` on `.gallery-item`s the margin is consistent.

Seems ok in chrome, ff and edge.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. That does work but then the items in the smallest view (1 per row) are no longer being centered. I used display flex to be able to use `margin: auto;` and align the items (when only 1 per row) in the center. Is there anyway to keep them centered?

Comment: The answer to the second problem was to put `align="center"` on `<div class="row">`